# How do I design arrow in a div including background image?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtSDH.jpg)
How do I add an arrow in a div including background image as shown in this image?

Comment: do right click > inspect element.

Comment: use  ::before and add background img in png format it's work

Comment: It would help to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following css you can generate image with arrow shape

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70%;
  height:150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.wrap:before, .wrap:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding-right:3%;
}

.wrap:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}

.wrap:after {
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform: skewY(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg);
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`   div::before {
               position: absolute;
               content: "";
               border-top: 20px solid transparent;
               border-right: 39px solid transparent;
               border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
               border-left: 40px solid green;
                 opacity: 0.4 !important;
               }`
```

Try to use position relative on main div.